# Shiny Data table - select radio buttons one after other without any user intervention

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I want to create radio buttons representing the levels of a column in a data-frame and then display the subset of data based on the value selected by radio button. I successfully implemented this bit but now I want to select these radio buttons in a loop with an interval of 5 mins after each iteration without ANY kind of user intervention. I would really appreciate any ideas/help. I have seen some examples with an action button to start a loop but I want to fully automate this process.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
   library(DT)
   ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    radioButtons("Categories",label = h2("Categories"),c("setosa"="setosa",
                                                         "versicolor"="versicolor","C"="virginica"))
  )

  )
  ,dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({   
    datatable(iris[iris$Species==input$Categories,]) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now I want to select these buttons one after another without any input from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [`invalidateLater`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/invalidateLater.html). To update every 5 minutes, replace `invalidateLater(1000)` with `invalidateLater(5*60*1000)`.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

my_choices = c("setosa"="setosa",
               "versicolor"="versicolor","C"="virginica")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    radioButtons("Categories",label = h2("Categories"),my_choices))
  )
  ,dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({   
    datatable(iris[iris$Species==input$Categories,]) 
  })

  observe({
    # invalidate every 1 second
    invalidateLater(1000)
    isolate({
      # Find index of currently selected choice, and then get index of the next one.
      # index %% mod n + 1, so goes back to 1 when index = n
      index = which(my_choices == input$Categories)
      index = index %% length(my_choices) + 1 

      # Update the radioButtons
      updateRadioButtons(session,'Categories',selected = my_choices[index])
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```